# Blackberry java.io.IOException radio is off

Tags: java, blackberry

I am trying to connect my device to a http server using wifi. But I am having this exception:

```
java.io.IOException radio is off
```

What is usually the cause of this and what should I check for?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Any code snippet which you are using may help us. Make sure you used "interface=wife" and your wifi in device or simulator is ON. And have a look at this [Blackberry Supportforum Thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Java-io-ioexception-radio-is-off/m-p/571238).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never had this error so I can't be sure. However it sounds as if your wifi reciever is turned off, try the following code.

```
if (RadioInfo.getState() == RadioInfo.STATE_OFF) {
        if (Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "You currently have no network connection\nDo you want to turn connections on?", Dialog.YES) == Dialog.YES)
        {
            //Activate GPRS
            Radio.activateWAFs(RadioInfo.WAF_3GPP);

            //Sleep for 10secs to allow wireless to activate. 
            // TODO (DG) DO THIS IN NEW THREAD TO PREVENT BLOCKING UI THREAD
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } }
```