# Required Radio is not active error in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, wifi, httpconnection

I am trying to fetch some web services from blackberry code. Heres the code I am using

```
public void execute(int method)
    {
        HttpConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            switch(method)
            {
                case GET:
                {
                    String combinedParams = "";
                    if(!params.isEmpty())
                    {
                        combinedParams += "?";
                        for(int i=0;i<params.size();i++)
                        {
                            String[] nameValue = SplitString.split(params.elementAt(i).toString(), ",");
                            String paramString = nameValue[0] + "=" + nameValue[1];
                            if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                            {
                                combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                combinedParams += paramString;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   if(combinedParams.equals(""))
                   {
                       System.err.println("URL = "+url);
                        connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url+combinedParams);
                   }
                   connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
                   executeRequest(connection);
                   break;
                }
                case POST:
                {
                    connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
                    connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
                    for(int i=0;i<headers.size();i++)
                    {
                        String[] nameValue = SplitString.split(params.elementAt(i).toString(), ",");
                        connection.setRequestProperty(nameValue[0], nameValue[1]);
                    }
                    if(getData()!= null)
                    {
                        OutputStream os = connection.openOutputStream();
                        os.write(getData().toString().getBytes());
                        os.flush();
                    }
                    executeRequest(connection);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

As soon as I run this line

```
connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
```

I am getting the error **Required radio is not active**

I dont have any sim card in the device but I am connected to a wifi and I can access other web pages from the browser.

What could be the possible reason for this error?

I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257063/blackberry-java-io-ioexception-radio-is-off) and the **RadioInfo.getState() is Off** in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html) on Connector:

> **Wi-Fi Support**
>
> Wi-Fi connection can be established by setting the interface parameter. This only works with direct TCP/UDP connections.
>
> **interface**:    If the `interface=wifi` parameter is appended to the end of the URI string value, a Wi-Fi socket connection is opened.

What this means is that you'll have to detect if the radio is off, and if it is you can attempt to use Wi-Fi by adding `interface=wifi` to the URL. A proper URL would be: `http://www.google.com;interface=wifi`

Comment: I hope this guy understands that if he puts "interface=wifi" sufix to the Connector than App stops working for end user if wifi is not connected.

Comment: Good point, you should definitely check to make sure the device is connected to a Wi-Fi network.